Auth Error: Windows Service Container to API Container Connection Issues
I’m currently working with two containers in my setup:

Container 1: API Container (mapped to port 80:8080, accessible via http://localhost/swagger)
Container 2: Windows Service Container

The API container generates a JSON file in a folder named Archive upon performing a specific action. I have mounted this Archive folder to the Windows Service Container, allowing the JSON file created in the API container to be accessible in the Windows Service Container as well.
The issue arises when the Windows Service Container attempts to connect to the API to execute certain functions. The first function it tries to perform is authentication, but it fails, indicating that the credentials from the Windows Service Container are incorrect.
In the appsettings.json of the Windows Service Container, I specified the API URL as http://localhost.
Has anyone encountered similar issues, or can anyone provide insights into what might be going wrong with the authentication process?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is the image of the log error for your reference.

